# how to run android studio emulator on nVidia GT 365M

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, intel, nvidia

I created an emulator via Android studio AVD. 
when i run the emulator, it show a message saying

```
your gpu driver information :
make:8086
Model:Intel (R) HD graphics 4000
device id :0166
Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version. As a result, were selecting a compatibility renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.
```

> https://i.ibb.co/60pY4pm/emulator2.jpg

I Added Android Studio to my nvidia card to run automatically on GPU driver whenever i open android studio 
I Also added emulator executive files to nvidia card control
So it supposed that the emulator run on My nividia GT 365M not intel 4000

> http://i63.tinypic.com/5bd7vk.jpg

But same message appear and my emulator is extremely slow 
it is on that stage after 15 min of running

> http://i66.tinypic.com/2zfv2hz.jpg

I tried every single option in emulator setting

> http://i68.tinypic.com/71jpm0.jpg

***I tried to run the emulator by command line

```
emulator -avd pixel -gpu on
```

But the same problem

**** I enabled Intel HAXM (intel hardware acceleratio),,,nothing changed

********I ensured that my nividia card Driver is up-to-date

My Laptop Specs

```
CPU Intel Core i5 (3rd Gen) 3210M / 2.5 GHz
*Number of Cores Dual-Core
*Cache 3 MB
*Ram: 6 GB
*Graphics Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000
*Graphic card : nVidia GT365M
```

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by installing intel 4000 graphic card update 
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81499/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000
but I still think my emulator runs on Intel card not GPU nividia card 
any solutions for that ?